# Visual Studio Code not updating file

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04

I'll preface this saying I am very new to programming in general.

Using Ubuntu20.4, attempting to edit a script within VSC as it's spitting out

'''
No such file or directory
'''

I attempt to change the line and run the script but it spits out the same error and not updating the .sh file. Why is VSC not changing the script file so I can correct the directory error?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I have opened a .sh file in the VSC editor. I run the script in the terminal window of VSC. It gives me an error stating the line of code it failed on. It says no such file or directory. I know the directory is there so I added a bit more clarification to the line by editing the script in the VSC editor.

I crtl+s and attempt to run the script again but the same error occurs with no change in the line statement. I check the .sh file manually and still nothing in the file has changed. I'm not sure why my changes are not being made.

Comment: add a screenshot of your terminal window into your question just to confirm you are in the right directory